# Azure Container Queue Function APP Connection String Error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, containers, azure-queues

I have created a azure container with a function app with a queue trigger.
I have also configured a scaling rule with connection string
[image]

This connection string is defined in secrets as a base64 string of an actual connection string.

[image]

But I am getting following error in the system log of the revision.

"can't parse storage connection string. Missing key or name"

Any help how can I fix this issue?

Comment: If you have stored the connection string as a base64-encoded string in secrets, you need to make sure that you're decoding it properly before using it. The error might be because you're trying to use the encoded string directly.

Comment: As a test try hardcoding the decoded connection string directly into the function wherever you're using it to see if it works. If it does, the issue might be with how you're retrieving or decoding the connection string.

Comment: I don't think I can decode it, It is defined in a secret and then secret is used in a scaling rule, so assumption is what secret rule will decode it.

Comment: I have tried both encoded or normal connection string but same error.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with your connection string.

1. Check if the connection string format is correct and complete with all the required parameters such as the account name, account key, and endpoint suffix.

- It should be in the below format:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account-name>;AccountKey=<account-key>;EndpointSuffix=<endpoint-suffix>
```

2. Connection string might not be accessible to function app.  Set the connection string as an application setting in `Function app=>Application settings=>configuration`.

[image]

3. Also, try using `AzureWebJobsStorage` app setting in your function with valid storage account connection string as its value.
4. Check if you have all the required permissions to process the request.